# Makefile:586: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed

Tags: python-3.x

I am re-installing python3.6.3 on Debian and got below error when executing make command. Who can help me on this. Thanks,
Segmentation fault
Makefile:586: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 139

Python 3.6.3 run smoothly, but after the power-cycle, Debian system failed to be up and asked to run fsck manually to recover the unexpected inconsistency of /dev/sda3. Then I did fsck /dev/sda3. When computer is up, I failed to run all the python scripts with segmentation fault.

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f47ad7c0700 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 159 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

Then I tried to re-install python 3.6.3 and saw the above issue when executing make command.